# How is soundso used?

Tags: word-usage

To translate:

> You can get it such-and-such a place.

I said:

> Du kannst es aus **soundso** **Ort** holen.

But some Germans corrected me with:

> Du kannst es aus **soundso** holen.

Why would one not include Ort here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they told you is a shortening. Your version isn't correct though.

> You can get it from **such-and-such a** place. — Du kannst es aus **soundsoeinem** Ort holen.

That *ein* is an integral component of that phrase. (In English, it's optional I think.)

Instead of *soundsoein X* you can often use *soundso* if the context suggests X. A plain *soundso* is otherwise used with adjectives.

> Ich habe es schon soundso oft gesagt.

> Zum soundsovielten mal habe ich es gesagt.

Comment: Or switch to a determiner: _du kannst es aus dem und dem Ort holen_.

Answer (score 2):

According to Merriam-Webster "such and such" used as an adjective means "not named or specified".

According to DWDS, the particle "soundso" (not the noun "Soundso") means:

"in einer bestimmten **Art und Weise**, die hier nicht genauer bezeichnet zu werden braucht, bezeichnet werden kann oder soll" (Emphasis by me.)

or

"drückt eine bestimmte Maßangabe, Menge, Zahl, Zeit aus, die hier nicht genauer bezeichnet zu werden braucht, bezeichnet werden kann oder soll" (i.e., soundso oft, soundso lange, soundso viele, ...)

These don't fit.

Then we have the noun "Soundso", which:

"bezeichnet einen bestimmten Namen, der in einem konkreten Zusammenhang nicht genauer bezeichnet zu werden braucht, bezeichnet werden kann oder soll
a) von Personen
b) von Dingen, **Orten** o. Ä." (Emphasis by me.)

However, I would only use that noun here if "such-and-such a place" is supposed to be a place with a proper name (i.e., a city, town or village).

I might translate instead as:

```
Du kannst es aus irgend so einem Ort holen.
```

Although I might translate "place"  differently but that depends on context.